# Javascript Array not Getting Sum. Instead of retrieving Array Itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

A function is Pushing value to "newdata" Array like this ["5.0", "68.0", "18.0", "5.0"] How can i add this values?

```
var newdata = ["5.0", "68.0", "18.0", "5.0"]
var total = 0;
for (i=0;i<newdata.length;i++)
{
    total = (total + newdata[i]);
}
alert(total);
```

When executing this function the result is showing the array itself! Not getting the Sum.

Comment: Try: `var total = [5, 68, 18, 5].reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; })`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parseFloat() to [convert the String in number](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert2.htm) :

```
var newdata = ["5.0", "68.0", "18.0", "5.0"]
var total = 0;

for (i=0;i < newdata.length;i++) {
    total = (total + parseFloat(newdata[i]));
}
```

console.log(total);

Comment: Paita, you have to change the `parseInt` to `parseFloat`. I made the same error in my initial answer :) The numbers in `newdata `aren't integers..

Answer (score 2):

In order you get the sum, you should try something like the following:

```
total = total + parseFloat(newdata[i],10);
```

or more compact

```
total += parseFloat(newdata[i],10);
```

In your code you just add the elements in the array called `newdata`, which are strings and not numbers.

Comment: You should use `parseInt(newdata[i], 10)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is comprised of strings, not numbers. Thus the `+` in the loop is performing string concatenation instead of numerical addition.

Declare the array as a list of actual numbers:

```
var newdata = [5.0, 68.0, 18.0, 5.0];
```

Or, if the array is coming from somewhere you can't control, convert each value in the loop:

```
for (i=0;i<newdata.length;i++)
    {
        total = (total + +newdata[i]);
    }
```

The unary `+` operator before the array reference will convert the string form of the number to a number.

Comment: How can i add values to array as numbers? By default it is adding as strings .

Comment: **What** is adding numbers as strings? Where is the code that puts new numbers in the array?